# Allowing WordPress.org/com accounts on a self-hosted install

Tags: comments, user-access

Hopefully a basic question, but one that plagues me nonetheless.

I have a couple of self-hosted WordPress installs on my website.   An issue that I have is that I have common users registered for each site....however some of them feel its a pain to have to go through the signup process each time, and have to juggle multiple accounts in order to comment.

Is it possible to commonize accounts, for instance simply using a WP.com/org account and accessing my blogs in that manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* WordPress.**com** [is an **OpenID Provider**](http://openid.net/get-an-openid/), meaning that you can use the OpenID Plugin, and allow users to use their WPCOM account to register/login to your site.

As far as I know, WordPress.**org** is **not** an OpenID Provider (though that would be a neat idea!).